# how to add asterisk after input field and the position same after zoom in

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap and glyphicons. i need to add asterisk after each mandatory fields. after zoom in i want the position keep same.

```
  <form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" 
    id="user_edit">
   <div class="form-group">

      <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
         <div class="input-group "><span class="input-group-addon">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
         <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" 
         name="first_name" value='<?php echo $profile_fields[0]["value"];?>' 
        id="first_name" maxlength="50" />
         </div>
      </div>
     </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle example so we can see what you mean? Thank you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pqash/gxro2xLf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just position the asterisk after the field using `::after`.  It should stay in the same position when the user zooms in.

```css
.required::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0;
  content: '*';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" 
    id="user_edit">
   <div class="form-group">

      <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer ">
         <div class="input-group required"><span class="input-group-addon">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
         <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" 
         name="first_name" value='' 
        id="first_name" maxlength="50" />
         </div>
      </div>
     </div>
 </form>
```

Note: Give all required fields (`input-group`) a distinct class, such as `required`.

Comment: is it possible if i want the asterisk to be before the fields. i try to change .required::after to before but not happen

Comment: You can do that.  You just need to change the positioning accordingly.  I updated the code snippet to demonstrate.

Comment: oh yes it works after i change the position accordingly. Thank you @Chava G

Comment: why i open on Firefox the asterisk position change? all okay in chrome

Comment: Welcome to browser quirks...  For Firefox you need to add `top` position.  I added that to the snippet - should work now in Firefox too.